# What is the reference to Ferris Bueler's Day Off in Spider-Man Homecoming?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, credits, spider-man-homecoming, ferris-buellers-day-off

In *Spider-Man Homecoming*, the credits reference Star Wars (that's easy to notice in the movie (Yoda, Deathstar) and Ferris Bueller's Day Off.

What and where is that movie mentioned in the movie? Seen it twice already, but couldn't locate that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ferris Bueller's Day Off* had a run sequence:

Spider-Man Homecoming did the similar sequence.

From [looper.com:](http://www.looper.com/59790/spider-man-homecoming-ferris-buellers-day-off-scene/)

> Speaking with [CinemaBlend](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1650029/one-lengthy-spider-man-homecoming-scene-will-be-inspired-by-ferris-buellers-day-off) during a set visit, Homecoming co-producer Eric Carroll revealed that there's a sequence in the film that pays homage to Ferris Bueller's high-stakes race to get home.
>
> > "[The characters] go through this great Ferris Bueller-inspired chase through this neighborhood, where these guys from the Shocker, they got in one good clock. Spider-Man was not expecting that," Carroll said. "So they get a jump on him, they tear off, and Spider-Man gives [into the] chase. It's a lot of fun. He's running through people's backyards, he's encountering friendly dogs, things like that. We think it's going to be one of the signature sequences in the film."

Comment: Thanks, but actually there are so many similar scenes out there, wonder why they picked this one. Thanks for reminding me how insane was that movie !!!!

Comment: Even they made  Tom Holland watch Ferris Bueller's Day Off for preparing of the role.

Comment: @Saariko There are lots of movies with running sequences, sure, but this is one of the more memorable examples from the 80s (which is probably - I'm guessing - a nostalgic era for Mr Carroll and the rest of the movie's writing staff.)  That's likely why they chose this movie over all others.

Comment: Didn't one of the of backyards Spider-Man ran through have people watching the movie as well?  Or am I remembering incorrectly?

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife don't remember that part but will try to dig more later

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife I remember that too, he even tells them it's a good movie.

Answer (score 7):

When he's chasing down the first Shocker (after the house party), and he's running through all the yards, there's a pool party with a TV playing the aforementioned "Race Home" scene.  You can see it right before Spiderman crashes into the pool.